# Place DropDown over UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

So I am using this framework for DropDown: https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown

I am trying to place the DropDown over my `UITextField`, but somehow it won't let me. It just shows in the top left, and goes all the way to right side. I have tried to set it up like this:

```
func setupDropDown() {
        dropDown.anchorView = view
        dropDown.direction = .bottom
        dropDown.frame = CGRect(x: screenRect.size.width/2 - 30, y: 70, width: screenRect.size.width/2 + 10, height: 30)


        dropDown.dataSource = myArray

        dropDown.selectionAction = { [weak self] (index, item) in
            self!.exerciseNameTextField.text = "\(item)"
        }

        dropDown.cancelAction = { [unowned self] in
            self.dropDown.deselectRow(self.dropDown.indexForSelectedRow!)
        }
    }
```

No matter what I change the `dropDown.frame = CGRect(...)` to, it doesn't change anything. Any ideas?

EDIT:
When I try their demo, it adds on the `UITextField`, but not over:

```
func setupChooseArticleDropDown() {
        dropDown.anchorView = exerciseNameTextField

        // Will set a custom with instead of anchor view width
        //        dropDown.width = 100

        // By default, the dropdown will have its origin on the top left corner of its anchor view
        // So it will come over the anchor view and hide it completely
        // If you want to have the dropdown underneath your anchor view, you can do this:
        dropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: exerciseNameTextField.bounds.height)

        // You can also use localizationKeysDataSource instead. Check the docs.
        dropDown.dataSource = [
            "iPhone SE | Black | 64G",
            "Samsung S7",
            "Huawei P8 Lite Smartphone 4G",
            "Asus Zenfone Max 4G",
            "Apple Watwh | Sport Edition"
        ]

        // Action triggered on selection
        dropDown.selectionAction = { [weak self] (index, item) in
            //self?.exerciseNameTextField.setTitle(item, for: .normal)
            self!.exerciseNameTextField.text = item
        }

        dropDown.multiSelectionAction = { [weak self] (indices, items) in
            print("Muti selection action called with: \(items)")
            if items.isEmpty {
                //self?.exerciseNameTextField.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                self!.exerciseNameTextField.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have set the direction of dropdown bottom  
dropDown.direction = .bottom.

Comment: @RamMani You also know how I can change the height/size of the `tableView`? `dropDown.frame.size.height = 20` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should set it using `dropDown.width = 100`. Check link under basic usage

[DropDown Readme](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown/blob/master/README.md)